# How Http runtime cache will respond if we inserting in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, outputcache

I know the question which I am going to ask will make no sense. Sorry to ask you anyway.

But I just want to know what will be happening, if I am inserting the same value to cache again and again.

```
Dictionary<Type, Attribute> Test ;
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
{
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("test", Test);
}
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), if the value exists already, it will be overridden.

> This method will overwrite an existing Cache item with the same key parameter

So if you call insert again on the same key, the cache will have the last value your "inserted"

Comment: @ Michac , Thanks for your replay . But one doubt I have ,WIl this piece of code create any harm to the app pool, or any application related issue.?

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly you are doing and why you want to cache a dictionary instead of just using the dictionary. The Cache is not much more than a dictionary itself ;) And no, it doesn't cause any harm to the app pool. It just stores what ever you throw into it, in memory, as long as the app pool lives. If the app pool stops, the data is gone, too